# Calculating the smoothing capacitor for a power supply

Tags: capacitor

Trying to build a simple 9V power supply using a 7809 voltage regulator and full wave rectifier. The load current from the regulator is 1A. So I = C*dv/dt, therefore,

C = I*t/(delta V)

[image]

To my understanding t is the time between the two peaks or the time the capacitor supplies the load. So if t is reduced, shouldn't the ripple increase ?, so isn't ripple (delta V) dependent on t ?, if so then why is delta V just arbitrarily chosen without considering t ?

Comment: Did you read the [other answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/134251/36731) in the post that the image comes from?

Comment: for 10%Vpp ripple load RC must be 8T for T=1/f  100Hz while Ic ripple (pp) current increases to 1/ %Vripple or 10x average current.

Comment: Look at the equation you wrote down: C = I*t/(delta V). It clearly has t dependency. Delta V should not be arbitrarily chosen, it should be chosen such that it meets the design requirements. Then you can use that to calculate the necessary C, with t being part of the equation.

Comment: Are you trying to select a filter capacitor for the unregulated DC supply rail that will feed your 7809? If so, you need to make sure that the minimum point is at or above the minimum required by the 7809, plus some comfort margin. And you wouldn't want excessive ripple, either. That might use a rule of thumb to get by. Or are you asking a bunch of other more detailed quantitative questions about how to actually predict what you'd see on an oscilloscope looking at the unregulated supply if you varied a resistive load on it or had selected a worst case load? It's not clear to me what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, if t is reduced (the AAC signal is of higher frequency) the time the capacitor ISS discharged over is reduced, thus ripple reduced.

That is all switching mode power supply is all about (almost), reducing the ripple by charging up a small capacitor at higher and higher frequencies.

Edit: you can think of the voltage as water level in a bucket with a hole on its bottom. The more frequently you can fill thee bucket, the less fluctuation in thee water level you see in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want ripple within 10%, it's fine to assume that current is constant (voltage is almost constant, so currency is also almost constant for given power). So just use this equation :

I * t = C * dV

This is in fact equation for constant charge: Q = CV => dQ = CdV.

Time is 8msec for 50Hz frequency (good empirical value).