# Output voltage of a rectifier

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

Is the output DC voltage of any rectifier (Halfwave, Fullwave or bridge) simply equal to \$\sqrt{2}\$ times Phase to neutral AC input voltage? Or does every rectifier circuit have its own formula to calculate DC output voltage?

Comment: actually, the output of a rectifier is not a DC voltage

Comment: I agree with @jsotola comment but more precise: the output voltage can be a DC voltage assuming there's a smoothing capacitor and you **do not load** the DC output. Then assuming the rectifier diodes have zero voltage drop (that will never be the case) then the DC output voltage will be \$\sqrt{2}\$ the AC input voltage. Phase/neutral is irrelevant. Also before even thinking about **formulas**, concentrate on **how a circuit works**. Would I hire an EE who knows **every** formula: No. Would I hire an EE who understands circuits? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring diode losses. If you measure the output voltage of a rectifier as the Root Mean Square (RMS) voltage you are getting a reading which reflects the amount of power that the source can deliver as compared to the equivalent DC voltage.

The RMS output of a full wave rectifier is the same as the RMS the original waveform. The squared bit removes the effect of half of the original waveform being negative giving the same answer.

The RMS output of the halfwave rectifier is half the value of the original waveform. The mean bit of RMS means you are taking the mean over a full cycle and you only have half of the original waveform there.

Things change if, as normal, you put a capacitor across the output of the rectifier then you get DC. In this case the capacitor charges to   √2 times the input voltage, this is the peak of the input.

If you take a load current from this arrangement you get a pulsating DC voltage. The pulsations value depends on the frequency the size of the capacitor and the current. This is well documented in other questions. See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134249/full-wave-rectifier-capacitance-calculation).

Answer (score 0):

Rectifier circuits include halfwave, fullwave, voltage doubler,
and voltage multiplier types.   A simple diode rectifier is
a halfwave type, and usually has significant forward voltage
and temperature dependence, and will have different output
current into different loads (in particular, a capacitor
load will cause higher forward-voltage losses and holds
the AC peak voltage).

There is no single formula for all rectifier/load combinations,
but there are lots of approximate ones that can be useful.

Most universal-input power supplies have voltage-doubler
rectification of 120VAC and bridge rectification of higher
voltages.   Many have phase-correcting modifications of the
input AC waveform.  Simple formulas aren't accurate in such
cases.